# Always alert me install python-gevent but I have installed it

Tags: python

I installed python 2.7.8 on Ubuntu 14.04
then I installed greenlet and gevent

but when I want to run a .py file:

```
    sudo python proxy.py
```

terminal shows :please install python-gevent

but I have installed it

How can I run this file...

I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have [python 2.7.5](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python) on 14.04, I guess that you installed 2.7.8 manually in `/usr/local` and that your python interpreter is `/usr/local/bin/python`.

The problem is that the new 2.7.8 interpreter cannot import the system modules installed by `apt-get`.

I'd recommend to remove the 2.7.8 version, that way your `proxy.py` script should work.

You can quickly test your script with 2.7.5 with:

```
sudo /usr/bin/python proxy.py
```

Comment: Oh,tks!My Ubuntu14.04 already have 2.7.6,I test the script with it,and it works well.At the begining, I want to update python version,so I download the package and copy the .tgz file to /usr/src,then install it manually.Now,I use **sudo apt-get remove python 2.7.8** to uninstall 2.7.8.But I don't know how to update newest version correctly.Can you tell me?

Comment: @oboorange Could you please accept my answer as it confirms that it was just your 2.7.8 version in `/usr/src` that prevented your script to run correctly? Regarding how to update to the latest 2.7 version, you can get it from the following ppa: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/ppa`

Comment: @oboorange No problem, good luck with your python script ;)

Comment: Hello,sorry bother you once again.I update python use your method.But I still can't use:`sudo python proxy.py`.Terminal still show _please install python-gevent_.But `sudo /usr/bin/python proxy.py` works well.And I find the script run with new python version.(not 2.7.6).I don't know why.

Comment: @oboorange: you need to remove the version that you installed in/from `/usr/src` I think. what's the result of `type python`?

Comment: I remove the 2.7.8 with `sudo apt-get remove python 2.7.8`.And I remove the folder `/usr/src/pythom-2.7.8/`.I changed my python path,so the result of `type python` is `/usr/local/bin/python`